# Python newline not working from form data to string formating

Tags: python, html, forms, newline, server-side-scripting

I am new to Python and trying server side form handling. I have a simple html page with three input fields and and a textarea. When user fill in the details the form is processed and user presented with all the details he filled in. My only issue is that I can't get new line to work while printing the data in the main program after htmlTop() function. Tried many ways but without luck.
Following is my code that I have tried so far.

---

```
#!C:\Python34\python.exe

import cgi

def htmlTop():
 print("""Content-type:text/html\n\n
     <!Doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
         <head>
           <meta charset="utf-8"/>
           <title> Server Template </title>
        </head>
        <body>""")

def htmlTail():
 print("""</body>
          </html>""")

def getData():
 formData = cgi.FieldStorage()
 firstname = formData.getvalue('firstName')
 lastname = formData.getvalue("lastName")
 email = formData.getvalue('email');
 message = formData.getvalue('message')
 dataList = [firstname , lastname , email , message]
 return dataList


#main program construct

 if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    htmlTop()
     data = getData();
     print("Welcome! {1} {0}".format(data[0],data[1]))
     print("\n" + "Your email is {0}".format(data[2]))
     print("\n" + "Your entered the following message: {0}".format(data[3]))

    htmlTail()
     except:
      cgi.print_exception()
```

Comment: You're missing a `"` after the `{0}` at `print("\n" + "Your email is {0}.format(data[2]))`.

Comment: That was a just typo while I was posting the questiion, I have tried, this way as well, e.g, "Your email is {0}".format(data[2])+"\n" but it still did not work

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, but what is `print` supposed to do here in relation to HTML? `\n` is Python, `<br>` maybe in HTML? Still, `print` is printing to stdout, not formatting it into any string.

Comment: Did you try using <br/> instead of "\n"? The former is the standard line break in HTML.

Comment: Indentation is wrong only here in the post as I was trying to properly insert the code into the post . In actual program indentation is fine. Will <br> work using print function?

Comment: Thanks I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<br>` to add a line break instead of a newline character.